# Why to use Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop

I am little confused about the usage of Hadoop. I dont understand when & where to use Hadoop.

> Hadoop is an open-source framework that allows to store and process
>   big data in a distributed environment across clusters of computers
>   using simple programming models. It is designed to scale up from
>   single servers to thousands of machines, each offering local
>   computation and storage.

According to the definition, this job also gets done by other databases like Oracle, MSSQL, etc i.e. storing & processing data across clusters. Then what else is the advantage of using Hadoop ?

Comment: You can check use cases for Hadoop at : http://hortonworks.com/use-cases/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hadoop is basically a distributed file system (HDFS) - it lets you store large amount of file data on a cloud of machines, handling data redundancy etc.

On top of that distributed file system, Hadoop provides an API for processing all that stored data - Map-Reduce.
The basic idea is that since the data is stored in many nodes, you're better off processing it in a distributed manner where each node can process the data stored on it rather than spend a lot of time moving it over the network.

Unlike RDMS that you can query in realtime, the map-reduce process takes time and doesn't produce immediate results.

On top of this basic scheme you can build a Column Database, like HBase.
A column-database is basically a hashtable that allows realtime queries on rows.

As per my knowledge, there are lot of differences. Please read below differences.

1. Hadoop is not a database.  Hbase or Impala may be considered databases but Hadoop is just a file system (hdfs) with built in redundancy, parallelism.
2. Traditional databases/RDBMS have ACID properties - Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation and Durability.  You get none of these out of the box with Hadoop.  So if you have to for example write code to take money from one bank account and put into another one, you have to (painfully) code all the scenarios like what happens if money is taken out but a failure occurs  before its moved into another account.
3. Hadoop offers massive scale in processing power and storage at a very low comparable cost to an RDBMS.
4. Hadoop offers tremendous parallel processing capabilities.  You can run jobs in parallel to crunch large volumes of data.
5. Some people argue that traditional databases do not work well with un-structured data, but its not as simple as that.  There are many applications built using traditional RDBMS that use a lot of unstructured data or video files or PDFs that I have come across that work well.
6. Typically RDBMS will manage a large chunk of the data in its cache for faster processing while at the same time maintaining read consistency across sessions.  I would argue Hadoop does a better job at using the memory cache to process the data without offering any other items like read consistency.
7. Hive SQL is almost always a magnitude of times slower than SQL you can run in traditional databases.  So if you are thinking SQL in Hive is faster than in a database, you are in for a sad disappointment.  It will not scale at all for complex analytics.
8. Hadoop is very good for parallel processing problems - like finding a set of keywords in a large set of documents (this operation can be parallelized).  However typically RDBMS implementations will be faster for comparable data sets.

Answer (score 2):

RDBMS is not capable of processing big data in a cost effective way. As the size of the data increases, the RDBMS systems which uses vertical scalability techniques will not work well. In this place, the big data processing frameworks such as hadoop work well in a cost effective way. 
Most of the big data processing frameworks are opensource and designed to run on commodity hardware. So the cost will be very less compared to that of RDBMS  required for the same set up.

In simple words, bigdata starts from where the RDBMS stops due to data size and complexity.
Another point is RDBMS mainly deals with structured data. But most of the big data frameworks can deal with Structured, Unstructured and Semi-structured data. Most of the big data frameworks are designed to process any kind of large data.

Answer (score 0):

Distribute data and computation. The computation local to data prevents the network overload. Tasks are independent so, it is easy to handle partial failure. Here the entire nodes can fail and restart.

It avoids crawling horrors of failure and tolerant synchronous distributed systems.Linear scaling in the ideal case. It used to design for cheap, commodity hardware.  Simple programming model. The end-user programmer only writes map-reduce tasks.

Comment: miss use of code block

Comment: @manetsus I tried to fix that, but it is still unreadable for me.